# Virtualbox connection with VMware

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware

I have a Windows OS installed on Virtualbox and a Ubuntu OS installed on VMware. I assign internal ip address for both OS(say 192.168.1.3 for Windows OS and 192.168.1.4 for ubuntu). The problem is I can ping successfully both servers from my local machine. But I can not ping these servers from neither Ubuntu nor Windows. Is there any idea?

**Edit:** It says "request time out" when I try to ping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have chosen the wrong adapter type. You should choose *Bridge* adapter for both of them. This way, they will ask your router for an IP address, and they will behave in every respect as new pcs on the network, capable also of talking to each other.

The internal adapter modes, instead, create virtual interfaces which are not immediately accessible to the user; for instance, if you try a NAT adapter, you will notice that on the *host* machine there is no new interface to talk to your VM at all: it is completely contained within the hypervisor.

The *bridge* connection is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't statically assign any IPs for those VMs. Instead of doing that here's what you need to do:

1. Close all the vms
2. Open VMware workstation, go to Edit-> Virtual Network Editor -> change settings -> select VMnet0 -> Under that select Bridged option and select "Virtual Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" -> click OK.
3. Open your VMware virtual machine (Ubuntu) -> go to network adapter settings of that virtual machine which you can find bottom of your VMware window.and then select Network Connection as Custom and select 'VMnet0'.
4. Open up virtual box and open your virtual machine(windows OS),go to setting of that virtual machine -> Network -> Attach to : Host-Only adapter and Name would be Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter.then click OK.

Now your connection is up.

More information is available at the following post, which I wrote: [How to Setup Network Between VirtualBox and VMware Virtual Machines](http://magcyber.blogspot.com/2017/03/how-to-setup-network-between-virtualbox.html)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While it's permissible to link to link to material you write elsewhere, it is good practice (and required!) to disclose affiliation- [see the FAQ for details](https://superuser.com/help/behavior).